# Java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError while listing docker images

Tags: java, docker, containers, devops

I am trying to list docker images  using java client api through  https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java

This my code snippet

```
import java.util.List;
import com.github.dockerjava.api.DockerClient;
import com.github.dockerjava.api.model.Image;
import com.github.dockerjava.core.DockerClientBuilder;
    public class StartContainers{
        DockerClient dockerClient ;
        public StartContainers() {
            startContainers();
        }

    public void startContainers() {

        dockerClient = DockerClientBuilder.getInstance("tcp://localhost:2375").build();
        List<Image> images = dockerClient.listImagesCmd().exec();

        for(int i=0; i < images.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(images.get(i));
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        StartContainers startContainers=new StartContainers();
    }
}
```

and I got this Exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError  at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.(JerseyWebTarget.java:71)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient.target(JerseyClient.java:290)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient.target(JerseyClient.java:76)
>     at
>   com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.JerseyDockerCmdExecFactory.init(JerseyDockerCmdExecFactory.java:234)
>     at
>   com.github.dockerjava.core.DockerClientImpl.withDockerCmdExecFactory(DockerClientImpl.java:161)
>     at
>   com.github.dockerjava.core.DockerClientBuilder.build(DockerClientBuilder.java:47)
>     at
>   com.cit.security.controllers.StartContainers.startContainers(StartContainers.java:18)
>     at
>   com.cit.security.controllers.StartContainers.(StartContainers.java:13)
>     at
>   com.cit.security.controllers.StartContainers.main(StartContainers.java:29)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create jax-rs
>   RuntimeDelegate   at
>   javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(RuntimeDelegate.java:149)
>     at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.(UriBuilder.java:56)

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe the environment where you are running that code?
I managed to run that code (as a maven project) with success on a Debian host, running the docker daemon as root (`sudo nohup docker daemon -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock &`) and started a dummy container.